# Where are Cognition Episode 4's saved games stored?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, cognition-an-erica-reed-thriller

Does anyone know where the saved games are stored in Cognition Episode 4? I am using a Windows 8 x64 PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Users\Computer\AppData\LocalLow\Phoenix Online Studios\Cognition _ Episode 4